# sortChanged event not working in ag-grid with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid with react; it has an event

```
  sortChanged={sortChanged}
```

According to this documentation http://54.222.217.254/javascript-grid-events/#sort-filter

But in my case it doesn't get called, I am not sure why.

What i can see from [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381989/how-to-listen-sortchangeevent-on-angular-for-ag-grid)  is that it is working in angular.

I tried to follow different syntax and went through its complete documentation but no luck.

This is my forged punker where i just want the alert hi just to know that user clicked to sort:
https://plnkr.co/edit/48MYV18mpAAuK27L?preview

I am trying like this:

```
  <AgGridReact
    defaultColDef={{ sortable: true }}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    rowData={rowData}
    sortChanged={sortChanged}
  >
```

and using it like this:

```
 const sortChanged = (e) => {
    alert("hi")
    console.log(e)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
const onSortChanged=(e: AgGridEvent)=> {
  e.api.refreshCells();
}
```

or

```
const onSortChanged=(e: AgGridEvent)=> {
   e.api.redrawRows();
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still facing some issues with this. Looks like docs are not updated and correct prop to the grid is `onSortChanged`

This way you can get sort state:

```
const onSortChanged = (e: SortChangedEvent) => {
  const sortState = e.columnApi
    .getColumnState()
    .filter(function (s) {
      return s.sort != null;
    })
    .map(function (s) {
      return { colId: s.colId, sort: s.sort, sortIndex: s.sortIndex };
    });
  console.log(sortState);
}
```

and the component:

```
 <AgGridReact
    defaultColDef={{ sortable: true }}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    rowData={rowData}
    onSortChanged={onSortChanged} //this is the main change
  >
```

Sources:
SortChangedEvent: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-sort

Sort State filter and mapping (saveSort function): https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-sorting/#sorting-api